# How to get obout grid CheckBoxSelectColumn value in code behind in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, obout

I have CheckBoxSelectColumn in obout grid. I want check whether a checkbox in the column is checked or not. I have tried different ways to retrieve the information, but I have been unsuccessful.

Please help me out.

```
<obout:Grid ID="mGrid" runat="server" >
     <ClientSideEvents OnClientSelect="Grid1_Select" 
         ExposeSender="true" />                

     <Columns>
         <obout:CheckBoxSelectColumn ShowHeaderCheckBox="false" ControlType="Standard" HeaderText="Select"  runat="server"   >

         </obout:CheckBoxSelectColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a property called `SelectedRecords` which you can use.

`mGrid.SelectedRecords` which returns you an ArrayList which consist of all the checkboxes you have selected.